# Run ansible playbook task-wise in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, ansible, node-modules

I want to run my ansible-playbook from nodeJS, it should display output task wise. I am currently using the **node-ansible** npm module, which displays all the task execution together at the end. Is there any other alternative npm module or a way for achieving this?